# window.location.replace() creates unwanted double quote

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting a strange double quote inserted into my HTML from my PHP script. I have tried all I know to prevent it but am at a loss'
Here is the code

```
<?php 

$Client_number =$_GET['client_number'];
$update_type =$_GET['input_type'];
$class_no = $_POST['class_name_sel'];
echo '<div class ="enter_stu_info">'; 
echo '<h2>Creating the following student records</h2>';
if ($update_type == "reg")
{
    require_once('../connections/i_connect.php');
    $stu_line_count = 1;
    $stu_temp = ($_POST['stu_first_name_'.$stu_line_count]);
    while($stu_temp!= ""){
    $first_name = $_POST['stu_first_name_'.$stu_line_count];
    $stu_surname = $_POST['stu_last_name_'.$stu_line_count];
 $employer_number =$_GET['client_number'];

    $reg_stu_query = mysqli_query($i_connect, "INSERT INTO is_student(first_name, last_name, class_no, employer) VALUES('$first_name', '$stu_surname', '$class_no','$employer_number')");
    echo 'First Name: '.$first_name.' Last name:'.$stu_surname.' Class_number: '.$class_no.'  Client_number: '.$employer_number.' ';
    $stu_line_count++;
    $stu_temp = ($_POST['stu_first_name_'.$stu_line_count]);
    }
if ($reg_stu_query){echo ' <h3>Entered</h3><br/>';}
}
if ($update_type == "blank_stu")
{
    require_once('../connections/i_connect.php');
    $no_of_students = $_POST['no_of_students'];
   $stu_line_count = 1;
   $employer_number =$_GET['client_number'];
    while($stu_line_count <= $no_of_students){


    $is_entered = mysqli_query($i_connect, "INSERT INTO is_student(class_no, employer) VALUES('$class_no', '$employer_number')");
    echo ' Class_number: '.$class_no.'  Client_number: '.$employer_number.'  Student number: '.$stu_line_count;
    if ($is_entered == "true"){echo ' <h3>Entered</h3>';}
    echo'<br/>';
    $stu_line_count++;
    }


}
$win_loc_txt = '"create_student_enter.php?client_number='.$employer_number.'&class_no='.$class_no.'"';
    echo'<br/>'.$win_loc_txt.'<br/>';

echo '<input name="more_stu_button" type="button" onClick="window.location.replace('.$win_loc_txt.')" value="Add more students">';

echo '</div>';
?>
```

This gives me the following result(note the unwanted double quote in the "window.location.replace() script between the "client_number=" and the "7" even though the echo of the variable used does not show the unwanted quotation mark..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="enter_stu_info">
<h2>Creating the following student records</h2>
First Name: testing Last name:testing Class_number: 1 Client_number: 7
<h3>Entered</h3>
<br>
<br>
"create_student_enter.php?client_number=7&class_no=1"
<br>
<input name="more_stu_button" onclick="window.location.replace(" create_student_enter.php?client_number="7&class_no=1")"" value="Add more students" type="button">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</body>
```

Comment: Umm... Replace `onClick="window.location.replace('.$win_loc_txt.')" value` with `onClick=\'window.location.replace('.$win_loc_txt.')\' value` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it because you're putting it there:

```
$win_loc_txt = '"create[...snip..] .'"';
                ^--------------------^
echo '<input [..snip..] onclick="window.location.replace('.$win_loc_txt.')" value= [..snip..]
```

When you put them together:

```
echo '<input [..snip..] onclick="window.location.replace("create...");" value=[.snip..]
                                ^------------------------^  ^--unknown/illegal attribute
```

Since you're prematurely terminating your `onclick` attribute, the browser is forced to try and GUESS what you intended and fix things as best it can.

You're dumping text from PHP directly into a Javascript context, inside an HTMl attribute, which means you have to generate valid javascript AND html, simultaneously.

Try something like

```
echo '<input ...' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($win_loc_text)) . '...';
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you were using `"` within a `"`, so your code should really be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="enter_stu_info">
<h2>Creating the following student records</h2>
First Name: testing Last name:testing Class_number: 1 Client_number: 7
<h3>Entered</h3>
<br>
<br>
"create_student_enter.php?client_number=7&class_no=1"
<br>
<input name="more_stu_button" onclick="window.location.replace(' create_student_enter.php?client_number=7&class_no=1');" value="Add more students" type="button">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</body>
```